# connecting wifi without networkManager

Tags: 10.04, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I re-install Network Manager without an internet connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection)

My friend has deleted network Manager. However, now she want connect Internet over using wireless. 
How can I manage that wish without Network Manager ?

EDIT: It was deleted by using ubuntu software center.

Comment: When you mean deleted? Do you mean the package or just the applet? You can easily add the nm-applet back even if it is deleted from the panel. Read these. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applets

Comment: It was deleted from software center.

Comment: possible dup of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection

Comment: @fatai If this is a different problem than the one you described in [How do I re-install Network Manager without an internet connection?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection), let me know and I'll re-open it. Looks like they're different questions trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution to your problem would be to install back NetworkManager.

But how do you install it back if you do not have Internet access?

It is possible to manually connect to the Internet using an Ethernet cable (technically it is far easier than a wireless connection).

Therefore,

1. connect the computer with an Ethernet cable to the router,
2. open a terminal window ('gnome-terminal') and run `dhclient eth0` (you should get Internet access now)
3. and finally start the Software Center and install `network-manager-gnome`.

Comment: No ethernet, do you have any Solution ?

Comment: You can perform a network connection using Wifi and WEP. Can you configure your wireless router to use WEP? (you can then change it back to WPA2). See my other answer below about getting online manually with WEP.