# How do I re-install Network Manager without an internet connection?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, network-manager

I have only wireless connection, one computer with a connection and 4gb usb .

My second computer has no network connection, because I have deleted it from the software center. However, now I want to re-install it. How can I do that?

Comment: If anyone reading this has a wired connection, just run `sudo dhclient eth0` (or whatever your device is called, see `ifconfig -a`).

Comment: @Josh Thanks, I was looking for that command, gave up and resorted to re-installing network-manager, then that search led me here. Worked instantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case you **only** removed **just** Network Manager with the Software Center it is quite easy to reinstall by downloading only 2 packages from another machine connected to the internet:

- Use [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), download the [network-manager package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/network-manager) from a software mirror close to you. Take care to choose the appropriate architecture (**amd64** for 64-bit, **i386** for 32-bit), and release version of your installed OS.
- Download [network-manager-gnome package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/network-manager-gnome) likewise (**amd64** or **i386**).
- Copy both files on your spare USB drive and take it to the broken machine.
  <sup>(e.g. network-manager-gnome_0.8xxx.deb and network-manager_0.8xxx.deb)</sup>
- Install **network-manager** and **network-manager-gnome** simply by double-clicking on these two .deb files. This opens the Ubuntu Software Center or Gdebi for reinstallation.
- After a rebooting (or just logging out and logging back in) the network manager will run and use your previous settings as before.

**Note:** This was not tested for the case when network-manager was removed in other ways, and if other applications were removed that may have deleted additional dependencies.

Comment: This answer made my day. 
I was reinstalling bluetooth and accidently purged `libbluetooth3` which is actually a dependency of the `network-manager`. My network immediately dropped, deadlocking broken dependencies since `apt` is not working without network.

I booted into Windows on my second drive, used the links provided to download and tried to install `network-manager` package which reported me which of its depencencies are missing. I downloaded their `.deb` files, installed them, installed `network-manager` and with network restored was able to run `apt --fix-broken install`.Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

The following describes how to establish a wireless network connection via command line utilities.

I think this is a better option because it gives you the useful ability to interface with relevant command line utilities.

1. Use `ifconfig -a` to identify your wireless card. From hence forward, I will assume it's `eth1`.
2. `sudo ifconfig eth1 up`
3. `iwlist eth1 scan` to find available networks. `iwlist eth1 scan | less` if it's a long list.
4. `sudo iwconfig eth1 essid [network] [key [pass]]` Also, read `man iwconfig` to figure out how the wifi password is entered. You might also need to configure the channel and stuff.

   1. If you use WPA, `wpa_supplicant` will be necessary. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263136
5. `sudo dhclient eth1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was on one and only computer - **off-line** and could not re-install Network manager. However, booting up in the root screen allowed an internet connection. I still could not install the network manager, but I was able to `apt-get install wicd`.

After doing that, I booted up again, this time to the GNOME window GUI and wicd was there in the applications. It sets up internet connection as does NetworkManager. But to be extra safe, I then installed network manager again since I was back online and able to do so. I have both now and feel more secure.

The first time a power line crash removed network manger and left me offline, I had to do a complete new installation as I did not know about wicd. I'm glad to have learned of it this time, and glad it is easy to install from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it, but my understanding is that you can enable the cd as a repository from in the software centre

[image]

[image]