# Ubuntu 12.10 - "the system network services are not compatible with this version"

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, ethernet

Fairly new to Ubuntu, know my way around, but novice user.

Started my Laptop running Ubuntu 12.10 this morning, and no wireless or Eth. Look at Network Manager and this message: "the system network services are not compatible with this version"

Running fine last night, installed and used tftpd-hpa no problem and then I shut down normally and restarted this morning. Nothing unusual, there may have been some updates yesterday, not certain.

restarted Services, rebooted, checked all usual.

Any ideas please thanks.

Comment: Found the answer... Somehow the Network-manager and network-manager-gnome got un installed

Comment: Follow this post to help with getting networks manually working http://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection

Comment: From a terminal... for Ethernet: sudo ifconfig eth0 up     sudo dhclient eth0