# Ubuntu 12.04.2 upgrade issue

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt

Before the upgrade (Ubuntu web server) was run, I had run `apt-get auto-remove`. Upgrade went forward and failed. Currently not able to connect to it. `sudo networkmanager` says:

```
command not found
```

Cannot run `apt-get install`, `upgrade` as it says `dpkg` was interrupted and asks to run

```
dpkg  --configure -a
```

but this get stuck at:

```
'Configuring postgresql-common' screen says 'the postgresql version 8.4 is obsolete...."
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

Comment: I don't have external connection at the moment. So if I run this command, does it require to connect to internet to download the postgresql-9.1 package?

Comment: And if I try and remove postgresql-8.4 using apt, it says the same "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem and then we do it all over again.

Comment: I assume that the postgresql-9.1 package has not been downloaded yet. So you should make sure to have internet access wenn you install. You can try to fix broken packages. See edit in my answer.

Comment: Sorry mate, I am not much used to Linux. May be wrong, but the issue primarily is that my networkmanager is not working! I cant connect anywhere, since its on VM, I can access it via a console and run commands. To fix the broken packages, I need to get my networking done, and to get networking done, I need to fix broken package. I kind of shot myself on the foot when I did  the cleanup I think!:(

Comment: What does "sudo service network-manager status" return?

Comment: network-manager : unrecognised service

Comment: This could help you fix the network-problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection

Comment: When I run dpkg -I *.deb, after mounting the files in an ISO on the CD drive on the VM and run, it says lots of other packages are missing and  : errors were encountered while processing "network-manager network-manager-genome" Should I try gnome-system-tools?

Comment: I guess you have to solve the dpkg-problem first. Try the first 3 commands of my answer. Maybe you need to run the dpkg --configure -a directly after the apt-get install -f and befor the postgres stuff.

Comment: Try to install only the network-manager package, without network-manager-gnome

Comment: Unfortunately nothing works. Moreover, I tried a repair and it comes back to the same screen with the Postgres message I mentioned in my first update (whenever I run dpkg --configure -a, it comes there)

Comment: Boot repair pastbin : http://paste.ubuntu.com/5629429/

Comment: "sudo dpkg -r --force-depends postgresql-8.4" will force the uninstall of the obsolete package without its dependencies. After that you should be able to run apt-get and install the new postgresql-9.1 manually (maybe after dpkg --configure -a).

Comment: Thanks mate, the solution at the postgres error was use the left arrow key! God sake! Now I ran dpkg --configure -a and gets to the error message which says error were encountered processing snmpd Linux-image-server Linux-server network-manager-genome

Comment: Maybe you should post a new answer and provide the complete output of "dpkg --configure -a"