# Downloading for bootable USB (lubuntu) - torrent vs download of standard image?

Tags: installation, lubuntu, usb-drive, bittorrent

I think I'd better apologize right away for probably kind of stupid questions, I'm a real beginner when it comes to Linux or basically setting up operating systems at all. Or, even computer stuff beyond using it to write or browse the internet...  However, I'm willing to learn and since my way is trying out and I have a netbook I hardly use (HP mini 210-1000), I want to give it a try; there's nothing to lose (except my dignity ;-))

So far I'm under the impression that I should try out lubuntu and I have a USB stick I can use for booting. I've been looking for download links and I wonder if I can use any of the lubuntu 13.10 32 bit links or do I have to observe some details if I don't want to burn it on CD but use the USB? For example, there is a link that says "standard image disc" and one that says "torrent file". Looking up "torrent file" and finding out that it has something to do with metadata has not really been helpful.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that everything has worked and I'm running Lubuntu on my netbook now. It was really easy, especially with your kind support, so thank you very very much. And happy New Year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu via USB stick, without burning a dvd, just download a standard ISO (an image containing the Operating System) and then use some tool to make a bootable USB with your new Linux on it, ready to be booted and tried/installed.
Some links for you:

link for Lubuntu 32bit:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso

and the one of the most useful tool to create a bootable USB pen drive with your favorite Linux  distribution - Unetbootin for windows:
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe

Fist of all, plug your USB pen drive.

Once opened Unetbootin, click on the "disk image" little button (left side of the window) and then on the [...], the three dots button on the left.
Now browse for your downloaded ISO file, choose it, click OK on the main window and wait for the whole process to end.

One of the advantages about using Unetbootin is that if the pendrive has sufficient free space, you don't have to format it, but you can have both your personal data and your Linux distribution for a live boot.

On completion, before rebooting the PC, be sure to set the BIOS to boot from the removable/USB drive, and not from the Windows partition. 
Most importantly, read something about the partitioning tool integrated with Ubuntu, and on how to install Windows and Linux side by side (it's really simple when you get the basics).

Good luck.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I hope I'll be able to do that. I hadn't even heard the word partition until two days ago ^^. Let's see if I can do this by midnight ;-) - good luck I will need. Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Ok, it seems everything has worked so far, I'm now told to restart the computer and choose the USB startup option in bios. Since I'm not sure if I know what to do, I watched the tutorial I found quite understandable, but there the guy formats the usb and he is using unetbootin, too. I've used a 4 gb sandisk usb drive, did I make a mistake?

Comment: Oh, and: when I restart my netbook, do I have to remove the USB first or can I leave it there?

Comment: after the bootable USB creation try restarting the PC without touching the BIOS. Maybe it's already configured to boot from the usb and you're done. Yes, keep the usb drive plugged while rebooting. If the PC boots again in Windows, you have to set the BIOS (or at least try pushing F8 a couple of times during first seconds of boot, and choose "USB" as boot device. Keep in mind that this last point may be different on your PC)

Comment: Ok, it did not boot from the usb and when Windows started, I pushed F8, as recommended. First the whole process seemed to be stuck somehow, but then it went on in Windows, I restarted and can now choose between five options, two of which are bood device options and bios setup. The first is the correct one, right?

Comment: OMG I think it works!

Comment: During the installation I figure I'm not connected to the internet :-/ - what do I do now? Like this? ---> http://askubuntu.com/questions/322861/how-to-connect-to-wireless-network-in-lubuntu

Comment: Never tested, but should work. Did it worked for you? ---- Anyway, if I may advise a Linux distribution, looking at your lightweight orientation, I would suggest http://www.linuxmint.com/ Look for the [Mate](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2493) flavour. More info on mate [here](http://mate-desktop.org/)

Answer (score 0):

> So far I'm under the impression that I should try out lubuntu and I
>   have a USB stick I can use for booting.

You could also consider [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) if Lubuntu comes up short. It uses the [xfce](http://xfce.org) desktop instead of the [LMDE](http://lmde.org) desktop and its apps and utilities are slightly more feature-ful.

> I've been looking for download links and I wonder if I can use any of
>   the lubuntu 13.10 32 bit links or do I have to observe some details if
>   I don't want to burn it on CD but use the USB?

Same download for USB vs DVD vs CD, alla same same.

> For example, there is a link that says "standard image disc" and one
>   that says "torrent file". Looking up "torrent file" and finding out
>   that it has something to do with metadata has not really been helpful.

A 'torrent' download uses the Bittorrent system where, once your machine downloads part of a file, it also uploads that to other folks seeking that file on Bittorrent. Wikipedia explains that [in greater detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file). You will likely finish the download more rapidly with a torrent IF you have a torrent client on the downloading machine, but it certainly is not required, and downloading the standard image is AOK.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm giving Lubuntu a try and when I can't handle it, I'll try out xubuntu. Most important: what I've downloaded is not completely useless and now I'll follow the instructions I found...  This is sooo exciting!

Comment: LMDE vs xfce is a matter of personal taste. If one does the job better for you, then by all means use it. I have found some things missing in LMDE but you may not.  And, OBTW, if an answer to your question is good, please click on the checkmark-on-circle icon at left to show it was good. You can change that later if a better answer comes up which meets your needs more directly. This also adds karma points to your rep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boot an Ubuntu environment from a external hard drive, [LinuxLiveUSB](http://linuxliveusb.com/) is a highly recommended software. They are also [very good documentation](http://linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide/preparation) on setting it up (shouldn't take more than 30 minutes).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll take a look at it right away. The file has been completely downloaded now, I hope I did the right thing...