# Install Network Manager after accidental removal

Tags: networking, software-installation, network-manager

I was installing some ARP tools and accidentally installed "arping" on my Ubuntu 13.04.

Now iputils-arping and network-manager have been removed. I don't have an internet connection on my laptop.

I tried to remove arping and install iputils-arping from a downloaded package, but it won't work because they are in conflict with each other. Also I can't install network-manager.

```
enn@em616:~$ sudo dpkg -i network-manager_0.9.6.0-0ubuntu7_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package network-manager. (Reading database ...
    212384 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking network-manager (from network-manager_0.9.6.0-0ubuntu7_i386.deb) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
    network-manager depends on iputils-arping; however:
    Package iputils-arping is not installed.

dpkg: error processing network-manager (--install):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:  network-manager
```

Comment: Why can't you remove `arping` and then install `iputils-arping`? That isn't clear in the question.

Comment: does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection ?

Comment: You should download and install `iputils-arping` first, then install network manager.

Answer (score 0):

Network manager is still installed, it's just the dependency that's not there.

Uninstall arping and find something that doesn't create conflicts.  Or try and find another source for it.  I dunno... I've installed arping and it never made dependency issues for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge arping
```

Reinstall the network manager, and apt-get will fix the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```