# Network manager deleted

Tags: 13.04, network-manager

I do not have a network manager on computer so I am unable to access internet. How can I install it using .deb packages?

I am running 64-bit 13.04.
I was trying [How do I re-install Network Manager without an internet connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55805/how-do-i-re-install-network-manager-without-an-internet-connection) but it didn't install Network Manager and network-manager-gnome. 
It said `Dependency not satisfiable: libgnome-bluetooth7 (>=2.27.8)`

Answer (score 1):

A .deb package is available from http://packages.debian.org to solve the jibgnome-bluetooth7 dependency:

- http://packages.debian.org/sid/armel/libgnome-bluetooth-dev/download
- Download and transfer it to the computer via USB, or SD.
- Double click on it to open, or use the terminal to install ( sudo dpkg -i libgnome-bluetooth-dev*.deb )
- The version is 3.8.1-2 which will satisfy the required >=2.27.8.

Once the dependency is installed you can then install network-manager from http://packages.ubuntu.com

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/network-manager-gnome
- Download and transfer it to the computer via USB, or SD.
- double click on it to open, or use the terminal to install ( sudo dpkg -i network-manager-gnome*.deb )
- A reboot or relog is required after install to activate the software correctly.

Would you be able to state why the network-manager is absent from your computer?

Comment: I have the exact problem. But trying to install the http://packages.debian.org/sid/armel/libgnome-bluetooth-dev/download I get the error message `wrong architecture:armel`

Comment: why a such program is absent? an erroneous prompt to `apt-get autoremove` useless packages when they are not useless at all. some people may think that `apt-get autoremove` is routine and don look twice