# Installing Network Manager on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, software-installation, 13.04, network-manager

I have deleted accidentally the network manager from Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Pavilion 13.04.
Now I am not able to connect to the internet using my laptop. I have downloaded the two .deb packages of network manager.

1:  network-manager-dbg_0.9.8.0-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb

2:  network-manager-gnome_0.9.8.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

I have followed the instructions from the following site.
   [Network manager deleted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347640/network-manager-deleted)

But when I unpack the network-manager-gnome from the terminal, it says:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network
>   manager-gnome: network-manger-gnome depends on network-manager (>=
>   0.9.8); Package network-manager is not installed. dpkg: error processing network-manager-gnome (--install): dependency problems -
>   leaving unconfigured

I also tried to install the network-manager package by double clicking on it, but the Software Center says:

> New software cant be installed, there is a problem eith the software
>   currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?

But there is no network access to do the repair.

What to do now?

Comment: The command "sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/network-manager_*.deb" could be useful but the package is not present in the archives folder of ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

No Network Manager doesn't mean that you can't connect to the internet. You just have to do it the good old way:

First bring your network interface up (assumed that `eth0` is your network interface):

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Assumed that your network is configured via [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), you have to 
receive an ip address:

```
dhclient -v eth0
```

Then set a default route (assumed that your router has the ip 192.168.1.1):

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

From now on you should be connected (if nothing went wrong) you can try by pinging Google via ip address:

```
ping -c 4 195.13.189.35
```

Last but not least, set the dns-servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` (assumed that your dns-server is 192.168.1.1):

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Now you should be able to ping Google by name:

```
ping -c 4 www.google.com
```

If this works, you can reinstall NetworkManager via apt or Software Center.

```
apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

But, don't just copy & paste my commands, they are most likely not the same as yours. If something went wrong, please post the output of the commands.

**Edit: If it's a wireless network interface (it's a bit tricky):**

Just go sure it's up

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

You should see your wireless network interface with the command

```
iwconfig
```

If it is recognized as a wireless interface, you can scan the network with (assumed that your wireless interface is wlan0):

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Then establish a connection to the essid:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "youressid"
```

Set the connection password:

```
iwconfig wlan0 key s:yourpassword
```

Hope you get an ip:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

Set the default route and the name servers as above.

Comment: The command "ifconfig" doesnot list the details of wifi interface card.

Comment: Uh, with a wireless interface it's a bit more complicated, see my updated answer.

Comment: While setting key for wireless network, the output is: Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) : SET failed on device wlano; Invalid argument

Comment: Your wrote `wlano`. That's wrong, type `iwconfig` to find out how your wireless interface is called, most likely `wlan0` not `wlano`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Exactly, its wlan0

Comment: I pinged google through the lan(cable) connection, but a 100% packet loss was resulted out.